# Как сделать, чтоб данные обновлялись сразу же, после 1 перезагрузки страницы?

Tags: php, html, mysql, ооп

Столкнулся с такой проблемой, что если рандомный товар не активен, то при добавлении нового рандомного товара приходится обновлять страницу дважды, сначала скрипт запишет в базу данные рандомного товара, при этом название и картинка останутся от неактивного товара, а после второго обновления страницы уже загрузятся новые.

Как сделать, чтоб данные обновлялись сразу же, после 1 перезагрузки страницы?

Код постарался подробно описать комментариями:

```
// Получаем данные рандомного товара
$random_product_select = $this->randoms->select_random_product(); 
    // Проверяем активен ли рандомный товар, если нет, то:
    if($random_product_select->active == 0){
    // Выбираем товар из всех товаров в базе
        $random_product = $this->randoms->get_random_product();
            if(empty($random_product) || (!$random_product->visible && empty($_SESSION['admin'])))
            return false;
            // Добавляем рандомный товар
            $random_product->id = $this->randoms->add_random_product($random_product);
    }
    // Получаем картинки и варианты товара по ID    
    $random_product_select->images = $this->products->get_images(array('product_id'=>$random_product_select->product_id));
    $random_product_select->image = reset($random_product_select->images);

    $variants = array();
    foreach($this->variants->get_variants(array('product_id'=>$random_product_select->product_id, 'in_stock'=>true)) as $v)
    $variants[$v->id] = $v;

    $random_product_select->variants = $variants;
        if(($v_id = $this->request->get('variant', 'integer'))>0 && isset($variants[$v_id]))
            $random_product_select->variant = $variants[$v_id];
        else
            $random_product_select->variant = reset($variants);

    $this->design->assign('random_product_select', $random_product_select);
```

Заранее спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Расскажите пожалуйста  поподробнее  в чем смысл записи в базу данных рандомного товара если вы оттуда его достаете, и как оно должно вообще работать из вашего вопроса не очень понятно что происходит, то есть понятно что при перезагрузке страницы должен появиться новый случайный товар , но вся остальная логика работы не понятна, вы что то куда то сохраняете? зачем?

Comment: @BroouzerKing, в таблицу рандомных товаров сохраняются такие данные как: срок действия(там еще таймер идет) , активность этого товара и в эту таблицу попадают товары добавленные за последние 30 дней

Comment: то есть если я верно понимаю у вас есть таблица случайных товаров которая переодически изменяется в зависимости от каких то там условий (таймера и тд), из этой таблицы вы при загрузке страницы выбираете и отображаете товар ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В общем решил я свою проблему вот так:

```
    $random_product_select = $this->randoms->select_random_product();
    if($random_product_select->active == 0){
    // Выбираем товар из базы
        $random_product_select = $this->randoms->get_random_product();
            if(empty($random_product_select) || (!$random_product_select->visible && empty($_SESSION['admin'])))
                return false;
        $random_product_select->id = $this->randoms->add_random_product($random_product_select);
        // После добавления еще раз делает выборку и обновляем переменную
        $random_product_select = $this->randoms->select_random_product();
    }

    $random_product_select->images = $this->products->get_images(array('product_id'=>$random_product_select->product_id));
    $random_product_select->image = reset($random_product_select->images);

    $variants = array();
        foreach($this->variants->get_variants(array('product_id'=>$random_product_select->product_id, 'in_stock'=>true)) as $v)
            $variants[$v->id] = $v;

    $random_product_select->variants = $variants;
    // Вариант по умолчанию
        if(($v_id = $this->request->get('variant', 'integer'))>0 && isset($variants[$v_id]))
            $random_product_select->variant = $variants[$v_id];
        else
            $random_product_select->variant = reset($variants);

    $this->design->assign('random_product_select', $random_product_select);
```

В конце if добавил еще раз

`$random_product_select = $this->randoms->select_random_product();`

чтоб обновить переменную и дальше скрипт работает корректно. Возможно это не самый лучший способ, но если кто-то напишет решение более корректное, отмечу.

Answer (score 0):

Кажется вижу вашу ошибку, вы при выборе картинки и других атрибутов товара используете  **$random_product_select->product_id** а должны использовать новый id  **$random_product->id**  соответвенно вам нужно переопределить переменную  **$random_product_select->product_id** на новый id и вместо

```
  $random_product->id = $this->randoms->add_random_product($random_product);
```

написать что ни будь вроде

```
  $random_product_select->product_id = $this->randoms->add_random_product($random_product);
```

или как нибудь по другому переприсвоить переменную если структура кода и вызовов не позволяет сделать именно так

Comment: Все правильно, там надо использовать новый $random_product->id, но я не понимаю как это сделать, перепробовал уже кучу всяких вариантов. Если написать так как вы посоветовали, то ничего не меняется.

Comment: ну подебжте, посмотрите заходит ли скрипт в if , действительно ли разные id  вы получаете при генерации нового товара, можете попробовать обнулить  $random_product_select ( $random_product_select=null) и понять на каком этапе у вас скрипт работает не так как должен, мне кажется самое узкое место тут это проверка на активность если id не изменяется то либо скрипт не входит в if либо возвращает тоже самое что и  было до этого , либо что угодно еще в зависимости от кода глубже в вызываемых функциях..